# ruby date format characters

Tags: ruby, date, formatting

I'm looking for a ruby date format character guide (like this one for php http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ) does one exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the correct answer, but I want to add two more resources for this topic:

- [An interactive strftime format string builder](http://haochi.github.com/strftime/) for various programming languages including Ruby.
- [stamp](https://github.com/jeremyw/stamp) - "Format dates and times based on human-friendly examples, not arcane strftime directives": a library that lets you build format strings by providing an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at the doc for [time.strftime( string ) → string](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-strftime).